# Cadaver WebDavTransfer Untrusted SSL Cetificate

Tags: linux, ssl, fedora, webdav, cadaver

```
cadaver -t https://ftp.example.com
WARNING: Untrusted server certificate presented for `*.example.com':
Issued to: Secure Link SSL Wildcard, site, site, S.L.U, Avda , M, M , 2, E
Issued by: Network Solutions L.L.C., H, V, US
Certificate is valid from Fri, 09 Sep 2016 00:00:00 GMT to Thu, 17 Oct 2019 23:59:59 GMT
Do you wish to accept the certificate? (y/n)
```

There is a way to accept this or put the certificate as trusted? I'm using amazon linux fedora.

I have a script that make a upload and he is not working because of this certificate.

Comment: May be helpful: "apt-get update", "apt-get install ca-certificates"